# Encrypt SVN for users group

Tags: permissions, password, encryption, svn, administrator

Could anyone advise how to encrypt SVN , Plan to encrypt or disable the SVN from asking if unencrypted passwords should be stored? We never want a user to be able to do that.

Is there possibility that users can bypass it and store their password in a plain text file anyway. If we disable the feature in the client binary, they'll download or compile a different client.

Is encrypt the users' home directory. to protect the passwords as well as the data will work ? If so how to do that ?

```
svn, version 1.7.14 (r1542130)
   compiled Oct  7 2020, 22:48:31

which svn
/bin/svn

whereis svn
svn: /usr/bin/svn /usr/share/man/man1/svn.1.gz
user group

getfacl /var/log/httpd
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/log/httpd
# owner: root
# group: devs
user::rwx
group::---
group:devs:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Do I need to go with mount a new volume for encryption. what is the best approach here ?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hello David ,I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .

Comment: That version is long past EOL and is not supported on this site. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using SSH public key authentication instead of passwords. Search for `svn+ssh` with your favourite search engine.